# Range by using array of booleans

Tags: php, arrays, boolean, range

hey guys I'm working a the range function for grades in the existing system that was already built,
the grades are stored as an array of booleans so for example:

```
[true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false...]
```

grade number is `element + 1`

I want to create a range function based on this array so, for example, this array the range is grade 1-6, any idea what is the most efficient way to do such thing, was thinking about running with loop and stoping the range when value is false, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: What if there is any true value after some false values?

Comment: probably wont happened but doesnt count, the range stops right where there is a false value after true one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping is obviously the most simplest way. There is no more efficient way unless we get to know more strict constraints or any modifications being done while storing the data itself.

There sure is a one liner for this where you can get the size of the range. So, the range is obviously `1 - size`. You can use `array_search` to get the index of the first element that is `false` and use this index the length/size of the range.

We use `array_merge` to deliberately add a dummy `false` value to make the function return the correct size in case of all truthy values.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

echo array_search(false, array_merge($d, [false]));
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/18ff0)

---

**Update:**

Looking at your new requirement, you can do like below:

```
<?php

$start = $end = 0;

foreach($d as $idx => $val){
    if($val){
        $end = $idx + 1;
        if($start == 0) $start = $idx + 1;
    }else if($start != 0){
        break;
    }
}

echo $start, " - ", $end;
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/0bd58)

Comment: Thanks! so i think i might stick with the loop solution, but then I thought about what if the first grades are false, how the loop would look like, do you have any idea how to handle this situation? @nice_dev

Comment: @nhnkl122 If first value is false, then range size is 0.

Comment: but leets say the array looks like that: [false, false, true,true, false] the range should be 3-4, instead of 0-4, i can make a flag telling me im in the first true value, but I don't find this optimal ;-; @nice_dev

Comment: @nhnkl122 Can you edit your question and add all the possible examples and their expected output?

Comment: @nhnkl122 Look at my updated answer in the update section. Having an extra flag doesn't make anything inefficient. What you are trying to achieve is micro-optimization which would give you very negligible gain.

Comment: This is actually what i was looking for, I was thinking about making it the most efficient, but you are right, making it micro optimized is not really possible here XD, ty buddy!

Comment: I kicked this question around before looking at this answer and my approach very much resembles this one. https://3v4l.org/4sLIZ

Comment: @mickmackusa What a coincidence :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually array_count_values help to count duplicate values in array, but if you have boolean values then it wont work.But array_filter can help for this to count boolean values.Here is the example:

```
echo $true_count = count(array_filter(array_values($array)));
echo $false_count = count($input_array) - $true_count;
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks

Comment: filter will return wrong range since if the array looks like that [false, false, true true, false], it would return [true, true], which cant really indicate on range, thanks tho!

Comment: @Suman It would still give incorrect range.

Comment: What is the point of `array_values()`?  You aren't assessing the keys anyhow.